# nodejs - jade ReferenceError: process is not defined

Tags: node.js, express, pug

the projcet is generated by webstorm's express template.

the npm dependencies haven be installed!

the result page is OK when I run the appplicaion, but the console will always say:

*'ReferenceError: process is not defined'*

why will this happened ?  I am under Win7 64bit.

Comment: Post code snippets, please.

Comment: Any time I load the 'jade' module into my node.js, 13 seconds pass during which [ReferenceError: process is not defined] is printed 27 times. The module works as advertised after that. I am on xubuntu - also a webstorm user. Jade is version 0.34.1

Looks like webstorm is a common factor. Maybe it runs node.js with dodgy arguments..

Comment: The problem only occurs for me in debug node. And only when running my app through webstorm. It seems to be an issue with the webstorm <-> node.js debugging integration. This thread may be related: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/442598

Comment: To see the issue, I only need the following code in my app.js:
require('jade');
return;
How is that for a minimal example? :)

Comment: Seeing the same issue in IntelliJ; here is a snapshot of a simple repo I'm working with (Node/Express/Jade/Jquery): https://github.com/swarajban/soundNexus/tree/IntelliJReferenceErrorSnapshot

Comment: The require('jade') fix did not work for me. [ReferenceError: process is not defined] In short, I can't debug with node with WebStorm, the regular debugger works, but not with WebStorm :(

Comment: It wasn't a fix. It was a minimal example reproducing the error. If it was a fix I would have posted it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally found where the issue originates. It's not Jade or Express, it's [Uglify-JS](https://npmjs.org/package/uglify-js) which is a dependency of [transformers](https://npmjs.org/package/transformers) which is a dependency of Jade which is often a dependency of express.

I have experienced this issue in [WebStorm IDE by JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) on Windows 7 and Windows 8 (both 64-bit).

I already went ahead and fixed the issue in [this pull request](https://github.com/Chevex/UglifyJS2/commit/7348facbe994aa1909a276b4be54f13c7f01e079).

All I needed to do was include `process` in the node vm context object. After doing that I received a new error:

> [ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined]

All I had to do was include `Buffer` in the vm context object as well and I no longer get those silly messages.

<strike>I still don't fully understand why it only happens during debugging but in my extremely limited experience I've come to find that the [node vm module](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) is a fickle thing, or at least the way some people use it is.</strike>

**Edit:** It's a bug in the [node vm module](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) itself. I figured out how to reproduce it and I figured out why it only happens during debugging.

This bug only happens if you include the third (file) argument to `vm.runInContext(code, context, file);`. All the documentation says about this argument is that it is optional and is only used in stack traces. Right off the bat you can now see why it only happens during debugging. However, when you pass in this argument some funny behavior begins to occur.

To reproduce the error (note that the file argument **must** be passed in or this error never occurs at all):

1. The file argument must end with ".js" and must contain at least one forward slash or double backslash. Since this argument is expected to be a file path it makes sense that the presence of these might trigger some other functionality.
2. The code you pass in (first argument) must not begin with a function. If it begins with a function then the error does not occur. So far it seems that beginning the code with anything but a function will generate the reference error. Don't ask me why this argument has any effect on whether or not the error shows up because I have no idea.
3. You can fix the error by including `process` in the context object that you pass to `vm.createContext(contextObject);`.

   ```
   var context = vm.createContext({
       console: console,
       process: process
   });
   ```

   If your file path argument is well-formed (matches the requirements in #1) then including `process` in the context will get rid of the error message; that is, unless your file path does not point to an actual file in which case you see the following:

   ```
   { [Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'c:\suatils.js']
     errno: 34,
     code: 'ENOENT',
     path: 'c:\\test.js',
     syscall: 'open' }
   ```

   Pointing it to an actual file will get rid of this error.

<strike>I'm going to fork the node repository and see if I can improve this function and the way it behaves, then maybe I'll submit a pull request. At the very least I will open a ticket for the node team.</strike>

**Edit 2:** I've determined that it is an issue with WebStorm specifically. When WebStorm starts the node process we get this issue. If you debug from the command line there is no problem.

Video: http://youtu.be/WkL9a-TVHNY?hd=1

Answer (score 1):

Try this...
set the webstorm debugger to break on all unhandled exceptions. then run the app in debug mode. I think you will find the [referenceError] is being thrown from the referenced fs.js.
More specifically, fs.js line 684:

```
fs.statSync = function(path) {
  nullCheck(path);
  **return binding.stat(pathModule._makeLong(path));**
};
```

These were my findings using the same dev environment as you. (win 64, webstorm, node, etc...)

from there you can use webstorms ***evaluate expression*** to re-run that line of code and see exactly why you are failing.

Comment: This helped me a lot. I still haven't fixed the issue but at least it's a start on the right path. Thanks for the ***evaluate expression*** tip.

Comment: Btw, I don't think this is where the "process is not defined" error is originating. If you break on exception you will always break on that line for `require()` calls because it checks a lot of paths that do not exist while trying to load the module. Unfortunately I don't think those exceptions mean anything with regard to this issue. However, I did manage to narrow it down in my app to the `require('jade')` call. I'm using Jade manually so it was easier for me to narrow it down to Jade.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error coming up and it was because I had the following at the top of my file:

```
const argv = require("minimist")(process.argv.slice(two));
const process = require("child_process");
```

That confused node, I guess it thought process hadn't been defined at that point.

Changing the second line to a different variable name resolved the issue